# Fitness plan suggestions?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, gym, machine

I am a 15 year old male, standing at a tiny 5 foot 6 inches and weigh in at 8 stone and 1.1 pound, my fat index is only 10.7% and from my research this suggests that I should go on a lean or "shredding" fitness plan. The problem is I only go to the gym once a week due to school and training. Is this a dieting problem or Can I do more in the gym? It could also be useful to note that I usually stay away from the freeweights section as it is usually packed! Can anyone recommend a fitness plan or even an app on android that could help me out? Cheers

Comment: What do you aim at. Let's keep the shredding plan aside, but what's your goal?

Comment: Truthfully at the minute I'm built like a stick figure! So my main goal would be to build muscle mass, not fat and to also define them at the same time! Also just to improve my general over all fitness, for example cardio endurance, but I would like the plan specifically for the strength part of it!

Comment: Thanks for the details. All I can say is, you are still growing and your idea of staying fit is quite impressive. There are several plans that asks for building mass. From your fat percentage it doesn't seem like you have too much, and also you are growing, hence you don't need to cut down your calories. If you get time to go one day to gym only, i'd say on other days do free-hand exercises at home like free hand squats, push-ups, lunges, and if possible get some weights to do curls?

Comment: If you want to gain mass why would you go on a shredding/lean diet?!

Comment: I wouldn't label 5 foot 6 inches as exactly "tiny"... Also you should still be growing so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I've converted units correctly, then "8 stone and 1.1 pound" is 113.1 pounds.  At 5 foot 6 inches -- which is not "tiny", in my opinion -- you are grossly *underweight*.  As @xCodeZone commented, "you don't need to cut down your calories"; on the contrary, please consider eating enough food to increase your total bodyweight to, say, at least 170 pounds.  Note that you cannot exclusively gain (or lose) muscle or fat: while gaining muscle, you'll gain some fat, and while losing fat, you'll lose some muscle.

In addition to eating more, I suggest heavy squats, deadlifts, and presses for your one day per week in the gym.  This will spur muscle protein synthesis, so you'll gain strength and muscular bodyweight (again, in addition to some fat, which you can lose after getting stronger and bigger).

Comment: Unless I'm doing it very wrong, the NHS's [Healthy Weight Calculator](http://www.nhs.uk/tools/pages/healthyweightcalculator.aspx) says that 5'6" and 8st 1lb is somewhere between the 21st and 30th percentile for a 15 year old and classifies it as a "healthy weight".

Comment: @PhilipKendall, thanks for your comment and the link to the NHS's weight calculator.  That calculator indeed says that OP's weight is healthy.  I own that my "you are grossly _underweight_" comment is my _opinion_, and that I am not a doctor.  I'll also opine that OP probably looks very thin, and might as well take advantage of being at nearly the optimal stage of physical development to build body mass.

Answer (score 0):

Goal: Build Muscle Mass

Experience: Beginner

- Diet: Tracked at a calorie maintenance + [GOMAD](https://stronglifts.com/gomad-milk-squats-gallon-gain-weight/)
- Exercise: [5x5 Stronglifts](https://stronglifts.com/)

Once you completed the above program, work out if you want to go for a "ripped" look or be strong af. And pick a suitable program accordingly. That is at least 6 months away.